Calculating Absences by hours and days between dates
The following query allows me to calculate in hours (if less than a day - converted to the portion of the day) or days (depending on the length absent), the difference between two dates:
Within the absences table, absences can be recorded as either 00:00 to 23:59, 08:30 to 16:30 (full working day) or a few hours in the day and sometimes even past the working day, examples would be 13:00 to 17:15. For my part I only want to calculate the portion up-until 16:30.
The issue I have with the query below is where the absence spans over a day and the end date is a portion of that day.
A working day is 8 hours (08:30 to 16:30).
For example dteStartDate = 13/04/2024 08:30 and dteEndDAte 15/04/2024 10:45
The query below gives me 3 working days for the example when the return I would like is 2.268 .
I have provided some sample data below of what I would expect:



dteStartDateTime
dteEndDateTime
Working Time Lost




27/02/2024 08:30
27/02/2024 16:30
1


11/03/2024 08:30
11/03/2024 16:30
1


12/03/2024 08:30
12/03/2024 16:30
1


13/03/2024 08:30
15/03/2024 10:45
2.28125


13/11/2023 11:05
13/11/2023 17:15
0.6775


31/01/2024 14:15
31/01/2024 16:30
0.28125



SELECT 
dteStartDateTime,
dteEndDateTime,
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, dteStartDateTime, dteEndDateTime) <= 1440 THEN 
            CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 
                          CASE 
                              WHEN CAST(dteStartDateTime AS time) < '08:30' THEN CAST(CAST(dteStartDateTime AS date) AS datetime) + CAST('08:30' AS datetime)
                              ELSE dteStartDateTime 
                          END, 
                          CASE 
                              WHEN CAST(dteEndDateTime AS time) > '16:30' THEN CAST(CAST(dteEndDateTime AS date) AS datetime) + CAST('16:30' AS datetime)
                              ELSE dteEndDateTime 
                          END
                         )/60.0 AS decimal(10,2))/8.0
        ELSE 
            -- Adjusting for weekends in multi-day absences
            (DATEDIFF(DAY, A.dteStartDateTime, A.dteEndDateTime) + 1)
            - (DATEDIFF(WEEK, A.dteStartDateTime, A.dteEndDateTime) * 2)
            
    END AS [Working Time Lost]

FROM TblCoverManagerAbsences A
JOIN TblCoverManagerAbsencesReasons AR ON A.intReason = AR.TblCoverManagerAbsencesReasonsId

OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT Min(txtStartDate) AS StartDate
    FROM TblSchoolManagementTermDates
    WHERE intSchoolYear = CASE 
                              WHEN MONTH(getdate()) BETWEEN 9 AND 12 THEN YEAR(getdate()) 
                              ELSE YEAR(getdate()) - 1 
                          END
) AS StartDate

WHERE 
    AR.txtName = 'Illness' 
    AND CONVERT(date, dteStartDateTime) >= CONVERT(date, StartDate.StartDate)
    AND CONVERT(date, dteStartDateTime) <= DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 6)

I'm not sure how I can incorporate this with having a secondary table of dates to lookup against and check each date for the date range.

Consumable sample data, and expected results, will help us help you here.

Also T-SQL is a SQL dialect that is used by multiple products including Sybase, SQL Server, and Azure Synapse. What is the (R)DBMS product you are using here? [Edit] your question to tag that product, and (if relevant) the version tag for the product as well.

can we have a db fiddle with sample tables and data

The content should be part of the question, @Developer , not as a fiddle (though a fiddle can compliment the question, it shouldn't be required for the data)

I have provided the data but as a screenshot from Excel. Is that sufficient?

What means dteEndDAte 15/04/2024 10:45 ? Is that 22:30 ? @Imran

"I have provided the data but as a screenshot from Excel. Is that sufficient?" No: Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

@ArtBindu no it's 10:45 in the morning.

Your 2.268 is wrong: you calculated 2.15/8 because the work last day was 2 hours 15 minutes while it should be 2.25/8: 15 minutes being 1/4th of a hour.

@p3consulting - Sorry corrected

Can I get sample data with some data so that I can try it out and give you the query. Sample tables and input here https://dbfiddle.uk/ER_9PaV-

What is Working Time Lost value ? is that an hour/minute/seconds/days ? @Imran

Try to use another table which contains all date information, is that a working day or non-working day (holiday or weekends)... That'll be best way to design query ... @Imran

Working time lost is the number of hours lost divided by the total hours that needs to be worked (8 hours per working day). So the result is converted to a portion of the working day if the absence is less than 8 hours.

@Developer - Sample data provided below:
CREATE TABLE TblCoverManagerAbsences (
dteStartDateTime datetime NOT NULL,
dteEndDateTime datetime  NOT NULL,
intReason int  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO TblCoverManagerAbsences  (dteStartDateTime, dteEndDateTime, intReason)
VALUES ('2024-02-27 08:30', '2024-02-27 16:30', 1),
('2024-03-11 08:30', '2024-03-11 16:30', 1),
('2024-03-13 08:30', '2024-03-15 10:45', 1),
('2023-11-13 11:05', '2023-11-13 17:15', 1),
('2024-01-31 14:15', '2024-01-31 16:30', 1);

@Developer table for the reason:
CREATE TABLE TblCoverManagerAbsencesReasons  (
intReason int NOT NULL,
txtName Varchar(50)
);
INSERT INTO TblCoverManagerAbsencesReasons (intReason, txtName)
VALUES (1, 'Illness')

Can you correct the tables and add so that I can verify https://dbfiddle.uk/vCi8cAR9

@Developer - Now corrected and updated: https://dbfiddle.uk/kmiVb7dS

The following seems to overcome my issue of the partial day absence on the last day. Comment included:
SELECT 
dteStartDateTime,
dteEndDateTime,
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, dteStartDateTime, dteEndDateTime) <= 1440 THEN 
            CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 
                          CASE 
                              WHEN CAST(dteStartDateTime AS time) < '08:30' THEN CAST(CAST(dteStartDateTime AS date) AS datetime) + CAST('08:30' AS datetime)
                              ELSE dteStartDateTime 
                          END, 
                          CASE 
                              WHEN CAST(dteEndDateTime AS time) > '16:30' THEN CAST(CAST(dteEndDateTime AS date) AS datetime) + CAST('16:30' AS datetime)
                              ELSE dteEndDateTime 
                          END
                         )/60.0 AS decimal(10,2))/8.0
        ELSE 
            -- Adjusting for weekends and partial days in multi-day absences
            (DATEDIFF(DAY, dteStartDateTime, dteEndDateTime) + 1)
            - (DATEDIFF(WEEK, dteStartDateTime, dteEndDateTime) * 2)
            - (CASE 
                  WHEN CAST(dteEndDateTime AS time) < '16:30' THEN 1 - CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST(CAST(dteEndDateTime AS date) AS datetime) + CAST('08:30' AS datetime), dteEndDateTime)/60.0 AS decimal(10,2))/8.0
                  ELSE 0
               END)
    END AS [Working Time Lost]

FROM TblCoverManagerAbsences A
JOIN TblCoverManagerAbsencesReasons AR ON A.intReason = AR.TblCoverManagerAbsencesReasonsId
JOIN TblStaff S ON A.txtTeacher = S.User_Code

OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT Min(txtStartDate) AS StartDate
    FROM TblSchoolManagementTermDates
    WHERE intSchoolYear = CASE 
                              WHEN MONTH(getdate()) BETWEEN 9 AND 12 THEN YEAR(getdate()) 
                              ELSE YEAR(getdate()) - 1 
                          END
) AS StartDate

WHERE 
    AR.txtName = 'Illness' 
    AND CONVERT(date, dteStartDateTime) >= CONVERT(date, StartDate.StartDate)
    AND CONVERT(date, dteStartDateTime) <= DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 6)


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

Thank you giving me opportunity to learn SQL Server Function:
Solution in SQL Server:
with T as (
  select *,
    DATEDIFF(day, dtestartdatetime, dteenddatetime) AS dateDiff,
    ((DATEPART(HOUR, dtestartdatetime)*3600) + (DATEPART(MINUTE, dtestartdatetime)*60) + DATEPART(SECOND, dtestartdatetime)) as loginTime_sec,
    ((DATEPART(HOUR, dteenddatetime)*3600) + (DATEPART(MINUTE, dteenddatetime)*60) + DATEPART(SECOND, dteenddatetime)) as logoutTime_sec
  from dailyLog
),
T0 as (
  SELECT
  cast('08:30:00' as TIME) as officialEntryTime,
  cast('16:30:00' as TIME) as officialExitTime
),
T1 as (
  SELECT
      ((DATEPART(HOUR, officialEntryTime)*3600) + (DATEPART(MINUTE, officialEntryTime)*60) + DATEPART(SECOND, officialEntryTime)) as officialLoginTime_sec,
      ((DATEPART(HOUR, officialExitTime)*3600) + (DATEPART(MINUTE, officialExitTime)*60) + DATEPART(SECOND, officialExitTime)) as officialLogoutTime_sec,
      (((DATEPART(HOUR, officialExitTime)*3600) + (DATEPART(MINUTE, officialExitTime)*60) + DATEPART(SECOND, officialExitTime)) -
      ((DATEPART(HOUR, officialEntryTime)*3600) + (DATEPART(MINUTE, officialEntryTime)*60) + DATEPART(SECOND, officialEntryTime))) as officialTotalTime
  From T0
),
T2 as (
  select T.dtestartdatetime, 
    T.dteenddatetime,
    ROUND(CAST(
     CASE
      WHEN(T.dateDiff = 0) THEN
          (T.logoutTime_sec-T.loginTime_sec)
      WHEN(T.dateDiff = 1) THEN
          (T.logoutTime_sec-T1.officialLogoutTime_sec) +
          (T1.officialLoginTime_sec-T.loginTime_sec)
      WHEN(T.dateDiff > 1) THEN
          (T.logoutTime_sec-T1.officialLogoutTime_sec) +
          ((T1.officialLogoutTime_sec-T1.officialLoginTime_sec) * (T.dateDiff - 1)) +
          (T1.officialLoginTime_sec-T.loginTime_sec)
    END AS REAL) / CAST(((dateDiff+1) * T1.officialTotalTime) AS REAL), 4) as Working_Time_Lost
  from T, T1
)
select * from T2;

Sample Output (SQL Server): db<>fiddle
Sample Output (MySQL): db<>fiddle
Output: 

Thank You !!!

This doesn't work for the 4th entry, which should result in 2.28 as opposed to 0.0938. I have a solution which I will paste below.

Yes, because you're provided all relative information in the query. According to your input data I design the query.
This query give you an approch, how to resolve this. So, my approach and your requirements make the perfect query.
If your issue is resolved, please accept the answer closed the ticket

@Imran read this article and upload your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
